# How to get document key in Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to migrate my existing Firebase realtime database over to firestore and update api calls in my mobile application. I am newer to Firestore and need some guidance. I am trying to fetch users in my database with this function:

```
        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            users = documents.map({ UserCollection(dictionary: $0.data()) })
        }
```

I am wanting to get the UID for the user, with realtime database I would always create a let value like this:

```
guard let uid = snapshot.key else { return }
```

I know firestore is different but I am not to sure how I can get the UID for my user with the new firestore collection methods. This is an example of how my Firestore collections looks like for users. Its set up like users -> UID -> user's information.
[image: Firestore]
Any recommendation on how I can get the UID for a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the document ID, use the `documentID` property of the `DocumentSnapshot` as shown in the documentation on [reading multiple documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection):

```
db.collection("cities").whereField("capital", isEqualTo: true)
    .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            }
        }
}
```